# UserInterfaceState file of Xcode4 gives trouble with Git and Subversion

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, git, svn

when committing or pulling I frequently get an error whith the file UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate which resides in the project folder. I'm not sure for what the file is good for, does anyone know?

Is it fine to just ignore it when committing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a [Git ignore file](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/) for those files. Here is a sample that I use:

```
    # Xcode
    build/*
    *.pbxuser
    !default.pbxuser
    *.mode1v3
    !default.mode1v3
    *.mode2v3
    !default.mode2v3
    *.perspectivev3
    !default.perspectivev3
    *.xcworkspace
    !default.xcworkspace
    xcuserdata
    profile
    *.moved-aside
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add those to your git/svn ignore settings. You only need to commit the project.pbxproj part of the project.